System starts to freeze when copying large amounts of data
OS is Debian 12. Got a brand new disk to use as a backup for a disk currently in use. For the initial rsync, my system starts to lag and freeze for maybe half a second at a time. This is especially noticeable when playing back audio.
Load average jumps from ~5 to ~15 during the rsync. What is going on here? I know it's rsync because the instant I kill the process, audio playback goes back to normal.
Trying to run with lowest cpu priority and lowest io priority like so:
sudo nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 rsync -a --sparse --delete --info=progress2 /mnt/src/ /mnt/dest

Running with sudo as a few files are owned by root and I want to be sure those get copied.
How can I run rsync so my system doesn't freeze?
Also I know it's not an issue with these specific disks, as I have tried other combinations of disks and I get the same issue. I also had this same problem on my older system, which used entirely different disks and motherboard.

Do you have swap? The free command will tell you.  Traditionally,  swap space of 1.5 x RAM is used. Idk if Debian 12 supports swap files, but man mkswap should tell you.

sudo swapoff -a will most likely help.

Try ionice -c3 instead of (in addition to?) nice.  Also would help to limit write cache for this command but that's trickier.  If you don't care how fast rsync runs, you can also explicitly tell rsync to limit bandwidth which might help but you'll have to play with the numbers.

I do have swap, but I am not sure how that relates to the issue here. I have a gig of swap, but 128 gigs of ram. I am nowhere close to running out of ram.

sudo swapoff -a has helped a bit, but there is still audio stuttering.

@user10489 Please check my original command, I am already using ionice -c 3, unless the space between the c and the 3 is causing the parameter to not get parsed correctly.

Probably works with or without the space.  Read it too fast, didn't see that was already there, sorry.

You can also try ionice -c1 on the sound process to give it real time priority.  However, this may already be default, and it doesn't solve the actual problem.  Gotta keep the copy from using up all your ram.  Disabling swap just keeps this from getting worse, it also doesn't fix it.

I don't notice an issue with ram at all. Right now, trying the rsync, I have 80 gigs of ram available and audio is lagging terribly.
